# How to add inline buttons under a keyboard in telegram bot by python

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm coding a telegram bot and would like to add inline buttons popping up below a keyboard instead of a message.

[Here is my source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X69bh.png)

[This is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAsg3.png)

[And this is an example of how it is supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2qDN.png)

Please, help me^_^

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `InlineKeyboardMarkup`, and in the target example `ReplyKeyboardMarkup` is used. The syntax is very similar, but the keyboard buttons will appear instead of message buttons.

I am not sure which library you are using, but here's [the documentation](https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup) from `telebot` library, maybe it will give you more context.